# Fitting two arguments while writing a csv

Tags: python, csv

```
z = option.split('.')
if z:
    print(id, z[-1])
f = open('bling.csv', 'a')
f.write(id, z[-1])
f.write("\n")
f.close()
```

I'm trying to write two specified columns in CSV but I get this error:

> f.write(id, z[-1]) TypeError: write() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

How to change it such that it takes two arguments?

I need assistance

I'm trying to do something like this in my csv file

```
desired csv file
12345,1
23456,1
56774,4
33221,2
```

Comment: What is `id` and why are you trying to write it? You're getting away without a `NameError` because `id` is a builtin function, but it doesn't appear to have any purpose in your code

Comment: id is a random number in a xml file..
im trying to write id and z into two separate columns in a csv file.. i want to use them and trying to learn how to implement a machine learning learning model

Comment: But you're not showing how it's generated. In any case, you should really be using the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module, where you can represent a row as a list when writing

Comment: ill update my question..im sorry

Comment: hi! i have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states `write` function only takes a single argument. In your case can pass a string.

**Ex:**

```
z = option.split('.')
if z:
    print(id, z[-1])
    f = open('bling.csv', 'a')
    f.write("{},{}\n".format(id, z[-1]))
    f.close()
```

Or using `csv` module

```
import csv

with open('bling.csv', "a") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow([id, z[-1]])
```